# App crashes on startup at Builder.UseMauiApp<App>()

Tags: maui

My app crashes with this error when builder.UseMauiApp() is invkied. Error is **System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler' threw an exception.**

There are no  custom buttons being used. Though we have the Telerik package, we have disabled it just in case to isolate any potential side effects. Here is my stack trace. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
`---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler' threw an exception.
 ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.microsoft.maui.PlatformInterop" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.Types.TryFindClass(String classname, Boolean throwOnError) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.Types.cs:line 97
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.Types.FindClass(String classname) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.Types.cs:line 36
   at Java.Interop.JniType..ctor(String classname) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniType.cs:line 49
   at Java.Interop.JniType.GetCachedJniType(JniType& cachedType, String classname) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniType.cs:line 104
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.get_JniPeerType() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.cs:line 83
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.GetMethodInfo(String method, String signature) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:line 58
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.GetMethodInfo(String encodedMember) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:line 34
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod(String encodedMember, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:line 150
   at Microsoft.Maui.PlatformInterop.GetDefaultColorStateList(Int32 color) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\obj\Release
et7.0-android\generated\src\Microsoft.Maui.PlatformInterop.cs:line 276
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ColorStateListExtensions.CreateDefault(Int32 color) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\ColorStateListExtensions.cs:line 9
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ColorExtensions.ToDefaultColorStateList(Color color) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\ColorExtensions.cs:line 33
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler..cctor() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Button\ButtonHandler.cs:line 20
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.microsoft.maui.PlatformInterop" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.onCreate(MauiApplication.java:28)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1025)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5405)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.microsoft.maui.PlatformInterop" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.onCreate(MauiApplication.java:28)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1025)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5405)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Button..cctor() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Button\Button.cs:line 16
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Hosting.AppHostBuilderExtensions.RemapForControls(MauiAppBuilder builder) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\Hosting\AppHostBuilderExtensions.cs:line 224
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Hosting.AppHostBuilderExtensions.SetupDefaults(MauiAppBuilder builder) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\Hosting\AppHostBuilderExtensions.cs:line 176
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Hosting.AppHostBuilderExtensions.UseMauiApp[App](MauiAppBuilder builder) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\Hosting\AppHostBuilderExtensions.cs:line 38
   at OCA.ReadyPay.Mobile.MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp() in D:\Software\OCA.ReadyPay.2\mobile\OCA.ReadyPay.Mobile\MauiProgram.cs:line 40
[0:] ********************************** UNHANDLED EXCEPTION. Application cannot start! Details: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Button' threw an exception.
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler' threw an exception.
 ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.microsoft.maui.PlatformInterop" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.Types.TryFindClass(String classname, Boolean throwOnError) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.Types.cs:line 97
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.Types.FindClass(String classname) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.Types.cs:line 36
   at Java.Interop.JniType..ctor(String classname) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniType.cs:line 49
   at Java.Interop.JniType.GetCachedJniType(JniType& cachedType, String classname) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniType.cs:line 104
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.get_JniPeerType() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.cs:line 83
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.GetMethodInfo(String method, String signature) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:line 58
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.GetMethodInfo(String encodedMember) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:line 34
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod(String encodedMember, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:line 150
   at Microsoft.Maui.PlatformInterop.GetDefaultColorStateList(Int32 color) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\obj\Release
et7.0-android\generated\src\Microsoft.Maui.PlatformInterop.cs:line 276
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ColorStateListExtensions.CreateDefault(Int32 color) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\ColorStateListExtensions.cs:line 9
   at Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ColorExtensions.ToDefaultColorStateList(Color color) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Platform\Android\ColorExtensions.cs:line 33
   at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ButtonHandler..cctor() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\src\Handlers\Button\ButtonHandler.cs:line 20
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.microsoft.maui.PlatformInterop" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.onCreate(MauiApplication.java:28)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1025)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5405)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.microsoft.maui.PlatformInterop" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.ocassociates.readypay-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at crc6488302ad6e9e4df1a.MauiApplication.onCreate(MauiApplication.java:28)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1025)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5405)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Button..cctor() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Button\Button.cs:line 16
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Hosting.AppHostBuilderExtensions.RemapForControls(MauiAppBuilder builder) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\Hosting\AppHostBuilderExtensions.cs:line 224
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Hosting.AppHostBuilderExtensions.SetupDefaults(MauiAppBuilder builder) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\Hosting\AppHostBuilderExtensions.cs:line 176
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Hosting.AppHostBuilderExtensions.UseMauiApp[App](MauiAppBuilder builder) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Xaml\Hosting\AppHostBuilderExtensions.cs:line 38
   at OCA.ReadyPay.Mobile.MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp() in D:\Software\OCA.ReadyPay.2\mobile\OCA.ReadyPay.Mobile\MauiProgram.cs:line 40`
```

I have commented out every single use of a button on every page but still the same problem.

Here is how we are using the buttons.

```
``<Button Text="Click To Test Printer" WidthRequest="200" Margin="5" BackgroundColor="Green" Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
                          IsEnabled="{Binding TestCommand.IsRunning}" FontAttributes="Bold"
                 TextColor="White">
            <Button.ImageSource>
               <FontImageSource FontFamily="FAS" Glyph="{x:Static utilities:FARegular.Print}" Size="12" />
            </Button.ImageSource>
         </Button>``
```

Comment: Did you try in a new project ? Seems like dependencies are missings

Comment: Have you registered required handlers for Telerik  inside the MauiProgram.cs? [Step 4: Register Required Handlers](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/maui/first-steps#step-4-register-required-handlers)